# Can't connect to home wifi consistently but can tether to mobile hotspot (Ubuntu 17.0.4)

Tags: wireless, 17.04

So as the title says I'm having problems connecting to my home wifi, to clarify, I can connect to the network and visually the wifi signal is full and looks normal but I get no response when trying to load/ping an address. Initially when I installed Ubuntu onto my laptop (in place of windows as primary OS) I would get internet access everytime I booted up except it would take about 5 minutes before it actually started connecting to the internet. The wifi net is stable and has no problems on other devices which made me believe it was the computer but the computer can connect and instantly use internet on other networks. I've tried forgetting the network as well as adding the line "wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no" to no avail. I'm pretty clueless when it comes to these kinds of issues and if anyone has any advice id appreciate it.

Comment: For accurate answers we need to know your WiFi adapter. Meanwhile also check the wireless encryption settings at the router and change it to WPA2-AES. Many Linux drivers don't work well with WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and/or TKIP. Reboot the router.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, as for the network adaptor I have "Intel corporation wireless 7265 (rev 59). As for the network thing, and again sorry this might sound stupid but changing it to wpa2-aes would that affect the windows devices also on the network? Thanks

Comment: It can only affect for the better but it's more likely you won't notice the difference.

Comment: The only options for wifi encryption are:WPA, wpa-psk, wpa2, wpa2-aes, mixed wpa2/WPA, mixed wpa2/wpa-psk

Comment: WPA2-AES only...

Comment: Lmao idk why I Included that (wpa2-aes) in the list but it's definitely not there when I go to wireless security settings (Linksys)

Comment: So start by selecting WPA2 and then, somewhere else it may have the selection for encryption type: AES/CCMP, TKIP, etc. (choose the former).

Comment: I've changed the settings and I still can't get internet Access

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=+7265